# Print out bit in int array

Tags: c++

i just read this link http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/255/Syllabus/1-C-intro/bit-array.html
i have a question ,im making an 128 bit array,so i use an array int A[4]. i can set Bit and test bit but how to print it those bits out ,for example 000001000.....? 
i used a simple code to print it

```
for(int i=0;i<128;i++)
{
cout<<A[i];// i tried cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(A[i]);
}
```

the result is  not what i'm looking for
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCaUS.png)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Don't spam tags. This is not C. And don't post images of text. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: If you declared an array of 4 `int` elements, referring to any element outside of indexes 0...3 invokes *undefined behavior*, something your code does 124 times over the course of that loop.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks,So can u instruct me some ways to solve it?

Comment: imho it isnt the best idea to use a C intro and apply it to C++. Especially when its content is based on facts like "The C programming language does not provide support for array of bits", because the C++ standard library has `std::vector<bool>` (which admittetly is a bit weird)

Comment: I'd use a [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) intead. [See it live](http://ideone.com/pXLuZT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the bits and print 0 or 1 according to the result.

```
for(int i=0;i<128;i++) {
    if((A[i/32]>>(i%32))&1) {
        cout<<'1';
    } else {
        cout<<'0';
    } 
}
```

or, simpler:

```
for(unsigned i=0; i<128; ++i) {
    cout << ((A[i/32]>>(i%32))&1);
}
```

(all this assumes that A is an array of some type which is at least 32 bit wide; ideally, that would be `uint32_t`)

Answer (score 1):

You are making a couple unfortunate assumptions:

- An `int` is not always 32-bit
- You have an array of 4x `int` variables, not 128x 'one-bit' variables

Prefer something like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h> /* uint32_t comes from here */

void main(void) {
    int i, j;
    uint32_t t;
    uint32_t data[4];

    /* populate the data */
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        data[i] = rand();
    }

    /* print out the 'bits' for each of the four 32-bit values */
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        t = data[i];

        /* print out the 'bits' for _this_ 32-bit value */
        for (j = 0; j < (sizeof(data[0]) * 8); j++) {

            if (t & 0x80000000) {
                printf("1");
            } else {
                printf("0");
            }

            t <<= 1;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
01101011100010110100010101100111
00110010011110110010001111000110
01100100001111001001100001101001
01100110001100110100100001110011
```